# dpkg-repack errors autoresolve?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I want to move to another installation, and I'm trying to use the dpkg-repack command to do it, but every time it comes across an application that is not perfectly installed, it quits. It will take forever to resolve it at this rate, as it is easily resolved by running sudo apt-get install  but I have to do it for each one, and then I have to start dpkg-repack from the beginning. I have a lot of packages, and not enough time to manually reconfigure every incomplete application installation along with wait for it to come to the next error and restart again. how do I either resolve all the errors at once or make it ignore the applications for which it experiences errors on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reconfiguration process of incomplete/interrupted installation, Try to use `dpkg --configure --pending` , then after all packages becomes fixed, then you start repacking them using dpkg-repack.

Comment: that did nothing, it just returned directly to the shell, no noticeable activity, yet I know there are errors that still exist